# The missing table name property

Tags: delphi

This is driving me nuts ....
I fetch the names of my databases to populate the cxComboBox1:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  DBList: TStringDynArray;
begin
  DBList := TDirectory.GetFiles(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), '*.abs', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
  for I := 0 to Length(DBList) - 1 do
  begin
    cxCombobox1.Properties.Items.Add(DBList[I]);
  end;
end;
```

This works OK.The list of my databases show in the cxCombobox1.

In the second cxCombobox I populate the table names that belong to the database
displayed in cxCombobox1.

```
procedure TForm1.cxComboBox1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  TABLES: TStringList;
  i: integer;
begin
  if ABSTable1.Active = True then 
    ABSTable1.Close;
  cxComboBox2.properties.Items.Clear;
  TABLES := TStringList.Create;
  ABSDatabase1.DatabaseFileName:=cxCombobox1.Text;
  try
    ABSDatabase1.Open;
    ABSDatabase1.GetTablesList(TABLES);
    for i:= 0 to TABLES.Count-1 do
      cxComboBox2.properties.Items.Add(TABLES[i]);
  finally
    TABLES.free;
  end;
end;
```

This basically works ok. Selecting the database in the cxComboBox1 populates the cxComboBox2
with pertinent tables.

So the general idea is to open the table when selected in the cxComboBox2.
And I did :

```
procedure TForm1.ABSTable1BeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ABSTable1.DatabaseName:= ABSDatabase1.DatabaseName;
  ABSTable1.TableName := cxComboBox2.Text;
end;
```

And on combobox2 change event I did:

```
procedure TForm1.cxComboBox2PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cxGrid1DBTableView1.ClearItems;
  ABSTable1.Open;
  cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.CreateAllItems;
end;
```

This works ok. But only when I open the tables from the selected database (combobox1)
that are displayed in the combobox2.
Say I have the table opened and then go select another database in the combobox1
I get the error "Missing ABSTable1.Tablename" !

What am I missing here? Where is my table name getting lost ?
If I replace the combobox2 on change event with a button :

```
procedure TForm1.cxButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ABSTable1.Active = True then 
    ABSTable1.Close;
  cxGrid1DBTableView1.ClearItems;
  ABSTable1.Open;
  cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.CreateAllItems;
end;
```

then everything works....

Comment: `cxComboBox2.properties.Items.Clear;` triggers the change event of combobox2. In the change event of combobox2, only open the database when a table is selected in combobox2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you call `Items.Clear()` in `cxComboBox1PropertiesChange` which raises a change event which in return results in a call to `cxComboBox2PropertiesChange`.

You should use `Items.BeginUpdate()` before any update and `Items.EndUpdate()` when you finished the update to avoid raising events on each updated step / item.

Comment: So you are suggesting I should use on cxCombobox1. change event :cxComboBox2.Properties.Items.BeginUpdate();
cxComboBox2.properties.Items.Clear; ??? Where do I use EndUpdate ?

Comment: Always call `EndUpdate()` in pair with `BeginUpdate()`. Therefore using a `try` `finally` construct fits perfectly here whereas `BeginUpdate()` is called before the try and the `EndUpate()` is called in the finally block.